# Parallel queries on CTE for writing operations in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-parallel-query

From [PostgreSQL 9.6 Release Notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/release-9-6.html#AEN130398):

> Only strictly read-only queries where the driving table is accessed via a sequential scan can be parallelized.

My question is: If a CTE (`WITH` clause) contains only read operations, but its results is used to feed a writing operation, like an insert or update, is it also disallowed to parallelize sequential scans?

I mean, as CTE is much like *a temporary table which only exists for currently executing query*, can I suppose that its inner query can take advantage of the brand new parallel seq-scan of PostgreSQL 9.6? Or, otherwise, is it treated as a *using* subquery and cannot perform parallel scan?

For example, consider this query:

```
WITH foobarbaz AS (
  SELECT foo FROM bar
  WHERE some_expensive_function(baz)
)
DELETE FROM bar
USING foobarbaz
WHERE bar.foo = foobarbaz.foo
;
```

Is that foobarbaz calculation expected to be able to be parallelized or is it disallowed because of the delete sentence?

If it isn't allowed, I thought that can replace the CTE by a *CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE* statement. But I think I will fall into the same issue as *CREATE TABLE* is a write operation. Am I wrong?

Lastly, a last chance I could try is to perform it as a pure read operation and use its result as input for insert and / or update operations. Outside of a transaction it should work. But the question is: If the read operation and the insert/update are between a `begin` and `commit` sentences, it not will be allowed anyway? I understand they are two completely different operations, but in the same transaction and Postgres.

To be clear, my concern is that I have an awful mass of hard-to-read and hard-to-redesign SQL queries that involves multiple sequential scans with low-performance function calls and which performs complex changes over two tables. The whole process runs in a single transaction because, if not, the mess in case of failure would be totally unrecoverable.

My hope is to able to parallelize some sequential scans to take advantage of the 8 cpu cores of the machine to be able to complete the process sooner.

Please, don't answer that I need to fully redesign that mess: I know and I'm working on it. But it is a great project and we need to continue working meantime.

Anyway, any suggestion will be thankful.

**EDIT:**

I add a brief report of what I could discover up to now:

- As @a_horse_with_no_name says in his comment (thanks), CTE and the rest of the query is a single DML statement and, if it has a write operation, even outside of the CTE, then the CTE cannot be parallelized (I also tested it).
- Also I found this [wiki page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Parallel_Query) with more concise information about parallel scans than what I found in the release notes link.
- An interesting point I could check thanks to that wiki page is that I need to declare the involved functions as *parallel safe*. I did it and worked (in a test without writings).
- Another interesting point is what @a_horse_with_no_name says in his second comment: Using DbLink to perform a pure read-only query. But, investigating a bit about that, I seen that [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/postgres-fdw.html), which is explicitly mentioned in the wiki as non supporting parallel scans, [provides roughly the same functionality using a more modern and standards-compliant infrastructure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/dblink.html).

  - And, on the other hand, even if it would worked, I were end up getting data from outside the transaction which, in some cases would be acceptable for me but, I think, not as good idea as general solution.
- Finally, I checked that is possible to perform a parallel-scan in a read-only query **inside** a transaction, even if it later performs write operations (no exception is triggered and I could commit).

...in summary, I think that my best bet (if not the only one) would be to refactor the script in a way that it reads the data to memory before to later perform the write operations in the same transaction.

It will increase I/O overhead but, attending the latencies I manage it will be even better.

Comment: "*can I suppose that its inner query can take advantadge of the brand new parallel seq-scan*" no you can't. The statement is considered DML and isn't a candidate for parallel execution. Don't forget the support for parallel queries in 9.6 is a first implementation and still has a lot of restrictions

Comment: One way to work around that might be to run the `select` through a DbLink (to the same server) which would then be seen as pure read only query.